# mysql_real_escape_string() error using xml2ary in Wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, xml

I created a plugin in order to replace some content in the post with information from a xml file. To parse the file I'd like to use [xml2ary](http://mysrc.blogspot.com/2007/02/php-xml-to-array-and-backwards.html) and the `wp_insert_post_data` filter.
I got the content replacement working with a *teststring* and I can also parse the **xml** in a script outside of WordPress.
But when I try to call

```
$data = xml2ary(file_get_contents($url));
```

inside of the plugin, I get the following error, twice:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in
>   {path}\testblog\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 774

plus another one:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   {path}\testblog\wp-includes\wp-db.php:774) in
>   {path}\testblog\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line
>   934

Here's my plugin code:

```
require_once("xml2ary.php");

if (!class_exists("Marketplace")) {
class Marketplace {

    function Marketplace(){

        add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'addInfo' , '99', 2 );
    }

}
}
     if (class_exists("Marketplace")) {
$marketplace = new Marketplace();
}

     if (isset($marketplace)) {

function addInfo( $data, $postarr ){    

$url = "http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/de-DE/apps/578ef361-c265-46b7-b6f4-63cbd7fbefe0?clientType=WinMobile%207.0";
$data = xml2ary(file_get_contents($url));

$data["post_content"] = "test";
$data["post_content filtered"] = "test";
return $data;
}

}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I shouldn't save my XML Array in $data. -.-